# Select value that doesn't exists in two tables

Tags: mysql

```
table1            table2             table3          Expected Result
-------------     --------------     -------------   ------
| id | col1 |     | id | col1  |     | id | col1 |   | id |
-------------     --------------     -------------   ------
| 1  | val1 |     | 2  | val1  |     | 3  | val1 |   | 1  |
| 2  | val2 |     | 2  | val2  |     | 3  | val2 |   | 6  |
| 3  | val3 |     | 4  | val1  |     | 5  | val1 |   ------
| 4  | val4 |     | 4  | val2  |     | 5  | val2 |
| 5  | val5 |     --------------     ------------
| 6  | val6 |
-------------
```

I want to select the id of table1 which are not in table2 and table3. For that, I have written a query, but it takes too much of time to execute. Please suggest me with a better query.

the query I have used is
`SELECT DISTINCT(id) FROM table1 WHERE yacht_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2 UNION SELECT id FROM table3 ORDER BY id)`

Comment: You could try a join and then basically select all values where the joins are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is fine, but an alternative is using `left join`s

```
select  t1.id
from    table1 t1
left join
        table2 t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
left join
        table3 t3
on      t1.id = t3.id
where   t2.id is null and t3.id is null
```

This will preserve all rows from `table1`, matching them with `null`s when the id is not available on `table2` or `table3`.

From there all you have to do is filtering for rows with `null` on both `table2` and `table3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN table3 c on a.id = c.id
WHERE b.id is null and c.id is null
```

Can you try this

Comment: don't you rather mean ...`LEFT JOIN table3 c` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try two separate In Clause

```
SELECT id
FROM table1 
WHERE yacht_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table2) 
   OR yacht_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table3)
```